# Can I prevent maximising of a window in WPF?

Tags: wpf

Specifically, not just by removing the buttons but completely disable maximising. This would mean that double-clicking the title bar or dragging the title bar to the top of the screen in Windows 7 would not work. I still want the window to be sizable though.

Comment: so its resizable?  doesn't that mean i can manually drag it to be the full size of the screen, and basicly maximized?

what's the point of making the window not maximizable?  what is so important about your window that i can stretch it to be full screen but not simply use the button i've always used forever to do the same?

Comment: Why do people consistently do this on StackOverflow? Rather than answering a question they start questioning why it is required. This is not helpful.

Just accept it as a requirement of the software and answer it if you know how or leave it alone. In this case the reason is because the customer wants to pay me many thousands of euro to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [CanMinimize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resizemode.canminimize.aspx) field .

Comment: That doesn't do what I want. I want to disable maximize but allow resizing. CanMinimize prevents resizing.

Comment: ...and changing people's spelling when it is not incorrect is rude. We aren't all American you know ;)

Comment: Sorry about that, although for what it's worth, "Maximize" matches the MSDN docs :)

Answer (score 1):

Removing Maximize from the system menu should be sufficient. I don't know if that will work for the Win7 "docking", let me know if it does.

Here's an article with a helper class for modifying the system menu of a window:
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/userinterface/article.php/c9327/

It assumes WinForms, but only because you need a window handle. In WPF this can be obtained with a WindowInteropHelper.

**Updated**

This code is UI Framework agnostic

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[Flags]
public enum SystemMenuFlags
{
    Unchecked = 0x0000,
    String = 0x0000,
    Disabled = 0x0002,
    Grayed = 0x0001,
    Checked = 0x0008,
    Popup = 0x0010,
    BarBreak = 0x0020,
    Break = 0x0040,
    ByPosition = 0x0400,
    ByCommand = 0x0000,
    Separator = 0x0800,
}

public enum SystemMenuCommand
{
    Size = 0xF000,
    Move = 0xF010,
    Minimize = 0xF020,
    Maximize = 0xF030,
    Close = 0xF060,
    Restore = 0xF120,
}

public class SystemMenu
{
    private IntPtr _menuHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    public IntPtr MenuHandle { get { return _menuHandle; } }
    private readonly IntPtr _windowHandle;
    public IntPtr WindowHandle { get { return _windowHandle; } }


    public SystemMenu(IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
        if (windowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The handle must point to a real window. Create only after your window object has created a real window.");
        _windowHandle = windowHandle;
        IntPtr menuHandle = GetSystemMenu(windowHandle, 0);
        if (menuHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The specified window does not have a system menu.");
        _menuHandle = menuHandle;
    }

    private SystemMenu(IntPtr windowHandle, IntPtr menuHandle)
    {
        _windowHandle = windowHandle;
        _menuHandle = menuHandle;
    }

    public static SystemMenu FromHandle(IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
        if (windowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The handle must point to a real window. Call FromHandle only after your window object has created a real window.");
        IntPtr menuHandle = GetSystemMenu(windowHandle, 0);
        if (menuHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            return null;
        return new SystemMenu(windowHandle, menuHandle);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            int count = GetMenuItemCount(MenuHandle);
            if (count < 0)
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            return count;
        }
    }

    private int GetItemPosition(SystemMenuCommand command)
    {
        int count = Count;
        for (int position = 0; position < count; position++)
        {
            int id = GetMenuItemID(MenuHandle, position);
            if ((SystemMenuCommand)id == command)
                return position;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public void InsertItem(int position, int id, string text)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
        if (!IsValidMenuIdValue(id))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("id", "Valid range for menu id is [0 .. 0xF000]");
        if (InsertMenu(MenuHandle, position, (Int32)(SystemMenuFlags.ByPosition | SystemMenuFlags.String), id, text) == 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    public void InsertSeparator(int position)
    {
        if (InsertMenu(MenuHandle, position, (Int32)(SystemMenuFlags.ByPosition | SystemMenuFlags.Separator), 0, String.Empty) == 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    public void InsertItemBefore(SystemMenuCommand command, int id, string text)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
        if (!IsValidMenuIdValue(id))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("id", "Valid range for menu id is [0 .. 0xF000]");
        if (InsertMenu(MenuHandle, (int)command, (Int32)(SystemMenuFlags.ByCommand | SystemMenuFlags.String), id, text) == 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    public void InsertSeparatorBefore(SystemMenuCommand command)
    {
        if (InsertMenu(MenuHandle, (int)command, (Int32)(SystemMenuFlags.ByCommand | SystemMenuFlags.Separator), 0, String.Empty) == 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    public void InsertItemAfter(SystemMenuCommand command, int id, string text)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
        if (!IsValidMenuIdValue(id))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("id", "Valid range for menu id is [0 .. 0xF000]");
        int position = GetItemPosition(command);
        InsertItem(position + 1, id, text);
    }

    public void InsertSeparatorAfter(SystemMenuCommand command)
    {
        int position = GetItemPosition(command);
        InsertSeparator(position + 1);
    }

    public void AppendSeparator()
    {
        if (AppendMenu(MenuHandle, (int)SystemMenuFlags.Separator, 0, String.Empty) == 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    public void AppendItem(int id, string text)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
        if (!IsValidMenuIdValue(id))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("id", "Valid range for menu id is [0 .. 0xF000]");
        if (AppendMenu(MenuHandle, (int)SystemMenuFlags.String, id, text) == 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    public void RemoveItem(int position)
    {
        if (RemoveMenu(MenuHandle, position, (int)SystemMenuFlags.ByPosition) == 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    public void RemoveItem(SystemMenuCommand command)
    {
        if (RemoveMenu(MenuHandle, (int)command, (int)SystemMenuFlags.ByCommand) == 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        GetSystemMenu(WindowHandle, 1);
        _menuHandle = GetSystemMenu(WindowHandle, 0);
    }

    public static bool IsValidMenuIdValue(int id)
    {
        return id > 0 && id < 0xF000;
    }

    #region p/Invoke

    [DllImport("User32")]
    extern static IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, int bRevert);
    [DllImport("User32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    extern static int AppendMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int uFlags, int uIDNewItem, string lpNewItem);
    [DllImport("User32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    extern static int InsertMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int uPosition, int uFlags, int uIDNewItem, string lpNewItem);
    [DllImport("User32", SetLastError = true)]
    extern static int RemoveMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int uPosition, int uFlags);
    [DllImport("User32", SetLastError = true)]
    extern static int GetMenuItemCount(IntPtr hMenu);
    [DllImport("User32")]
    extern static int GetMenuItemID(IntPtr hMenu, int nPos);

    #endregion
}
```